# How to get value of textboxes created at run time on button click event in asp.net web application using c#

Tags: c#, dynamic, reference, textbox, null

I am working on asp.net web application using c# visual studio 2012. I have created textboxes and labels on runtime and on button click I want to fetch the value inputted by user at run time in the textboxes. But as soon as I click on the button I get error **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
 I am new to asp.net. Kindly Help

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddEntity.aspx.cs" Inherits="GraphWebApplication.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server"><title></title></head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server"  Width="396px" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <asp:TableRow HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Entity Name" Width="193px"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="193px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>

                <asp:TableRow HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="No. of Attributes" Width="193px"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="197px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="6" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="7" Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="8" Value="8"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="9" Value="9"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="10" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>

            <br />

            <div align="center"><asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
            <asp:Table ID="Table2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="396px">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell Width="193px">
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add More Entity" Width="163px" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell Width="193px">
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Next Step:Add Relationship" Width="170px" OnClick="Button2_Click"/>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>

            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>

            <br />       
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace GraphWebApplication
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a = Convert.ToInt16(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);

            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
            {
                Label labels = new Label();
                labels.Text = "AttributeName" + (i + 1).ToString();

                TextBox textBoxes = new TextBox();
                textBoxes.ID = "TextBoxAttributeName" + (i + 1).ToString();
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(labels);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(" "));
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(textBoxes);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<BR>"));
            }

            DropDownList1.Enabled = false;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a = Convert.ToInt16(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);

            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
            {
                TextBox tt = (TextBox)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("TextBoxAttributeName1");
                Response.Write(tt.Text);

                //Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx");
            }
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "AddRelationship", "<script>AddRelationship();</script>");
            //Response.Redirect("~/WebForm2.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save your current number of attributes into Session and in the OnInit method you can add the Controls (Label+Textbox) to the Placeholder. OnInit gets called before Page_Load. The eventhandlers get called after Page_Load. So in the Button1_Click method the controls are already added to the Placeholder (because the OnInit method added them) and .FindControl will find the controls.

Because you are new to asp.net forms, another thing for better understanding. You maybe wondering: How can the values I've entered into the textboxes still be in the textboxes after you hit the "Add more entity" button? NEW textboxes will be added in the OnInit method, so how can the have the .Text property properly set? This is because of the ViewState. The ViewState will be loaded after the OnInit method and will fill your form elements with their former values.

Also, if you will do this with Session always be careful. (for example: delete the session variables when you don't need them anymore, ...)

Here is my new code behind:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.UI;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

  namespace WebApplication1
  {
     public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
        private int AttributesCount
        {
           get
           {
              int ret = 0;
              if (Session["AttributesCount"] != null && int.TryParse(Session["AttributesCount"].ToString(), out ret))
              {
                 ;
              }

              return ret;
           }

           set
           {
              Session["AttributesCount"] = value;
           }
        }
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
           base.OnInit(e);

           RenderTextboxes();
        }

        private void RenderTextboxes()
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < AttributesCount; i++)
           {
              Label labels = new Label();
              labels.Text = "AttributeName" + (i + 1).ToString();

              TextBox textBoxes = new TextBox();
              textBoxes.ID = "TextBoxAttributeName" + (i + 1).ToString();
              PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(labels);
              PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(" "));
              PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(textBoxes);
              PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<BR>"));
           }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           int a = Convert.ToInt16(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);

           AttributesCount = a;

           RenderTextboxes();

           DropDownList1.Enabled = false;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < AttributesCount; i++)
           {
              TextBox tt = (TextBox)PlaceHolder1.FindControl("TextBoxAttributeName" + (i + 1));
              Response.Write(tt.Text);

              //Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx");
           }
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "AddRelationship", "<script>AddRelationship();</script>");
           //Response.Redirect("~/WebForm2.aspx");
        }
     }
  }
```